# Google Charts - graph not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This bit of code is meant to display a chart, but doesn't:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    data.addcColumn('string', 'Type');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Job Registration');
    data.addRows([
  <?php foreach ($chart_result as $result) {
            echo $result;
        }?>  
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Job Registration by Type',
      hAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

When I submit the form and view page source, this is the result for data.addRows:

```
data.addRows([
  [' Engineer',1],['Assistant',1],['Developer',4],[' Ninja!',1],['Web Application Developer',1],  
    ]);
```

This looks right to me, but this is the first time I've used Google Analytics (or JavaScript...) and I was following an example of an existing chart rather closely, so maybe it's not right at all. Any ideas why this might not be working?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.

The first is that you don't define the data.

Add the following line to your code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

The second is a silly syntax error:

```
data.addcColumn('string', 'Type');
```

Should be:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
```

And with those, like magic, it works:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Job Registration');
  data.addRows([
    [' Engineer',1],
    ['Assistant',1],
    ['Developer',4],
    [' Ninja!',1],
    ['Web Application Developer',1],  
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Job Registration by Type',
    hAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```